# library to detect overlapping communities in a network?

Tags: java, networking, graph, cluster-analysis

Looking for a lib that detects overlapping communities in a fairly large network (up to 10,000 nodes) in seconds, not minutes?
[note: by "network" I mean a graph]

---

Responding to a comment asking for details, here is a simple example:

D-E-F
     |
    G
      |
A-B-C

There are many algorithms that are able to detect (D,E,F,G) and (A,B,C) as 2 distinct (non overlapping) communities in this network - or of course, (D,E,F) and (A,B,C,G).

I am looking for an algorithm, implemented in Java, that would be able to detect (D,E,F,G) and (A,B,C,G) as the two overlapping (because they overlap on G) communities in this network.

Comment: Providing a bit more detail would be helpful. Could you give an example of a small network, how communities are defined in such a network, and what you would expect to find?

Comment: @seinecle, did you find anything in the end?

Comment: I could not find a solution

Answer (score 2):

Try, SNAP Tool from Stanford University. They have this use case in the examples folder already implemented.

http://snap.stanford.edu/

Comment: I could not find it. Can you post the precise link please?

Comment: In the examples folder, you will see cliques. http://snap.stanford.edu/snap/description.html says about - cliques: Finds overlapping dense groups of nodes in networks, based on the Clique Percolation Method. How ever, I'm unsure if that does in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try [gephi](http://gephi.org/features/). I believe that what you plan to do is already implemented there. However, it is open source (3 GPL) and you can get some ideas from the code. The java Graph API description is [here](http://gephi.org/docs/api/org/gephi/graph/api/package-summary.html).

Also you might want to review [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.0612v2.pdf) article

Comment: gephi detects *non* overlapping communities with the Louvain algo

Comment: this is neither good or bad - just not the feature I am looking for. Non overlapping communities means that nodes in the network belong to one community or the other, but not several (communities are disjoint, so to say). I knew of the article you mention thx! Just found this one too: http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5813 - but that's not about implementation

Comment: I have a good lead here: http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~steve/networks/software/conga.html

Comment: could you elaborate on the problem you are solving? e.g if you the problem is given 2 subsets of set of nodes of G (lets cal them A and B) find the subset C that belong to both A and B the solution is linear. If the problem is to find subset of nodes of proximity k to nodes in A and in B that is more complicated. If the problem is finding all overlapping communities given graph G that is NP hard. So which one are you looking for?

Comment: I'll keep it simple: I am looking for an algo that detects (possibly overlapping) communities based on "the strength of division of a network into modules" (Newman's modularity): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_(networks)

Answer (score 0):

COPRA is an algorithm for overlapping communities implemented in JAVA and it is very fast.

http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~steve/networks/software/copra.html

Other useful links for overlapping clusters (not necessarily written in java) are:

MOSES: cliquecluster.org/moses

OSLOM: oslom.org/

OVERMAP: bitbucket.org/dsign/grbracket/wiki/Home

Stochastic Block Model: github.com/premgopalan/svinet